# Find the domain of the function (it's a square root polynomial)

Tags: polynomials

Find the domain of the function:
$$f(x)= \sqrt{x^2 - 4x - 45}$$

I'm just guessing here; how about if I square everything and then put it in the graphing calculator?
Thanks,
Lauri

Comment: I believe you mean $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* The domain of a function is the set of input values for which the function is defined. Do you know of any values for which the square root is not defined?

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)$ is not defined when $$x^2 - 4x - 45 \lt 0,\tag{1}$$ as the square root function is defined in the reals for non-negative reals only. The only valid "input" for the square root function is non-negative real numbers.

If a function $f(x)$ is not defined on an interval(s) = $I \subseteq \mathbb R$, or is not defined for any particular $c\in \mathbb R$, then the interval(s) and/or points at which $f(x)$ is ***not defined*** are ***excluded*** from the function's ***domain***.

So what are you left with if you exclude all $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $x^2 - 4x - 45 < 0$? This amounts to excluding your solutions to the inequality given in $(1)$. What remains in $\mathbb R$ is then your domain.

Alternatively, your domain consists of all real $x$ such that $$x^2 - 4x - 45 \geq 0\tag{2}$$

Then your task would then be, essentially, to determine the solutions to the equality given by $(2)$. its solution will be your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^2-4x-45=(x-2)^2-49$.  We completed the square. This is an almost universally useful move when we are dealing with quadratics.

Now when is the thing under the square root sign bad (negative)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just happened to run into a mathematician yesterday (in person) and he just pulled the polynomial out of the square root and added the "greater than or equal to"symbol.Because, a square root number can't be a negative number,but it can be zero. Then we just factored it and  it factored out to (x+5)(x-9), which leaves the domain at -5 and less and also at 9 and more.I graphed it and it came out to be right.
    This is the first time I used this site and I don't see where you get the math expressions to type. Maybe because I didn't join as a member?
Lauri